# Large HashSet of org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer objects exists on ThreadLocal

Tags: hibernate, tomcat7, java-7

My application deployed on **Tomcat 7.0.29**, **Spring 3.2.5**, **Hibernate 4.2.7** and **Java 7u45**. 
During Tomcat stop phase I see inside catalina.out log file the following lines:

```
Sep 23, 2014 3:07:20 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/MyApplication] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e2ae389]) and a value of type [java.util.HashSet] 
(value [
[org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@23467a0b
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@5ba7dd2a
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@6387a4d7
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@27b8a1c8
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@790e1cd7
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@143d7953
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@3e50f1be
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@685eb02d
 org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer@77fc3a07
 .
 .
 .
```

Total 18.5K values inside one hash set on the specific thread local, look like a memory leak.
Didn't find any references to same issues on the web, any ideas what can lead to it?

Comment: +1 for finding an issue during the stop phase. Very good tested!